# Install Python module with Sypder

Tags: python, module, installation, spyder

I am new to Python, but very excited to learn! However, I am having difficulty installing a Python module using Spyder on a Mac.

First, I go to the directory with the setup.py file.

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/UserName')
```

Then, I attempt to install the module.

```
ez_setup.py install
```

I receive the following error.

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ez_setup.py install
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any advice on what is going wrong? I have looked around, but I cannot find an explanation of what may be going on in this case. It seems like module installation should be easy.

Comment: Are you trying to run this from within Spyder or in the Terminal app?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, from within Spyder. I take it that's not the way to go?

Comment: I thought so :) Right now Spyder doesn't offer the possibility to install new modules within it (but we have plans to do it in the future). The answers quoted by @RobBW are the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `python ez_setup.py install` ?

When using a .py file, you have to give it to python executable :)

Edit: You can have a look on this page - http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Vincent! I tried the command you mentioned, but it didn't work; I received the same error.